# What should I keep instead of this energy harvester breakout for maximum efficiency of the solar and supercaps circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, supercapacitor, energy-harvesting, solar-energy

This is my circuit which charges the supercapacitors. The problem with the circuit is the minimum input voltage require to get 3.3 volts output. Once the input voltage goes below the certain level ( i guess ~4.2 volts ) then breakout board does not give 3.3 volts as an output. As per the circuit, I do need 3.3 volts constant.

Should I use boost converter from 2.7 volts to 3.3 volts?

Please give some suggestions of IC or circuits.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0vL2v.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Components:

[Energy Harvester](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9946)

**EDIT:**

This project is about powering few LEDs (let's say 3 LEDs) with the solar panel. LED specs are 2.6 volts and 2 mA. The solar panel could be of any voltage and dimension. I prefer to use 5, 6 or, 9 volts small panels. I used LDR to sense the presence of the light with the LM393 comparator and TI SPST switch IC for switching. My original goal is to be able to use it for a long time at least 16-18 hours. Thus, I used super caps to store energy.

Temperature range: -20 to 52 deg C

LED: 2.65 volts and 2 mA [datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Kingbright/WP7113LVBC-D/?qs=%2fha2pyFaduhrePTw2dVb6PCFKCZqgI4ARLqITlzg6T2ZrJApZuSJlA%3d%3d)

Solar PV source power: 0.6 W [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HQ9CUMO)

desired load power: 0.02 W

work time: 24 hours (after 'power-bank' is fully charged and LEDs are triggered by the sensor)

sensor: LDR (I would love to use other sensors like current as LDR could give false detection with some occlusion)

project time: 30 days

Comment: I see two initial problems so far, 1) the LTC3588 is designed for piezoelectric energy harvesting (short high voltage pulses) so it's not ideal for solar (which has kinda the opposite requirements) and 2) what's to stop your caps from exploding if you're feeding 9V into a 5.4V supercap bank?

Comment: Converting a low current Solar Panel @ 9V to a charge 2 capacitors from 0 to 2.7V (x2 with balancing) then buck-boost to   blue LED @ 3.1V at constant current is probably the worst application (in terms of efficacy, size, cost, complexity, impedance matching etc.) of using two 50 F supercaps.  Consider a  1 or 2 LiPo 18650 cells (3.3 to 3.7V) , it will be 10x more efficient and smaller with 1 or 2 LEDs or some other application. PV efficiency drops with load voltage below 82%Voc. Boost converters cannot make use of all the charge to 0V.

Comment: @Sam For (1) what would you suggest for solar application? I need to drive 3 LEDs using solar and supercaps. (2) While designing, I thought that diode would block the current once the caps are fully charged.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Thank you. I thought of using super caps as they can store more energy and I do not need to replace them for a long time. My application requires having a solar panel as input and 3 LEDs as output. It should work for at least 10 years. What would you suggest?

Comment: I would suggest you list ALL the specs and requirements

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I just edited my answer. There are no constraints for PV cells specs. But, the smaller size should be preferable.

Comment: Diodes don't stop conducting when caps get charged, they stop conducting when reverse biased, this means the voltage of the caps has to be *higher* than than of the solar panel for the diodes to prevent current flow, they are *not* voltage limiters. The diode will happily allow current to flow from the panel into the caps right up until they explode provided that the panel voltage is higher than the cap voltage. [Here's a list](http://www.linear.com/parametric/energy_harvesting) of energy harvesting chips from Linear tech, note the third column "Energy Source", you want a buck or buck-boost.

Comment: @Mat_python when I say "list ALL the specs" I mean like in a datasheet for a system. ie actual light device, desired load power , duty cycle, source power, duty cycle, temperature range, budget, R&D time , etc etc.  . The better you understand all the requirements, the better the design can be. Without sufficient detail,  it is not possible.  Is this just a perpetual dim LED?  Then You can get long life with a LiPo and 3.9 ~ 4V max solar cell with a current limiting R or fancy MOSFET constant current comparator with low side drive to Cathode. Excess power can be dumped to LED or other zener.

Comment: given the poor performance of $1 garden PV LED lights, with no/poor battery and insufficient PV size, you can expect cost to increase. Start by estimating PV size needed for 10mA and duration. mAh , efficiency, solar emissivity etc.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I have updated the question with more details as you have asked. There are no constraints on initial budget. I am not sure about LiPo's temperature range and life-span. Which one are you suggesting to?

Comment: @Sam You are right. I made a mistake about the diode, and I have changed it in my circuit. What do you recommend for the circuit/block diagram using a Linear Tech IC?

Comment: @Mat_python Well, for the "circuit diagram" I'd recommend whatever the reference design is, the vast majority of chips in the world have reference designs in their schematics. Example circuits that you *know* work (it's how the manufacturers show off what their products can do). Linear tech is particularly good in this regard as they tend to pack their datasheets chock full of example circuits. They've got energy harvesting chips for RF, chips for piezoelectric transducers, for solar panels, for peltiers (energy from heat), some also have battery/supercapacitor charging circuitry built-in.

Comment: @Sam Sure. I shall try that and get back to you. Thank you

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Do you have any suggestions? Please let me know. Thanks